# android studio latest version gradle update problem

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to updated my project which I was working on like 2016, I was updating everything within the code from the gradle version to 28.0.0

While updating an error came up that I have never seen:

```
Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...

this is line 28 from the code build.gradle (   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'   )


Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...


implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'


implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

I tried updating everything to latest version and checking from android studio libraries, but I failed maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some research about the error. I found that to solve this you should migrate to AndroidX.
This is a full documentation about how to migrate:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

The conclusion is to migrate to AndroidX you should follow these steps:

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

The refactor command makes use of two flags. By default, both of them are set to true in your `gradle.properties` file:

`android.useAndroidX=true`
The Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library.
`android.enableJetifier=true`
The Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries.

Comment: after migrating i got a new error

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Comment: @LastCode You can try to clean and rebuild the project, check your internet connection, or check your gradle version or dependencies

Comment: still received the same error maybe i share to you the code via github link you check?

Comment: sure @LastCode . I would love to help you

Comment: below is the link
https://github.com/mzunye-777/twitterclone.git

Comment: sorry @LastCode I though it was flutter not java. I don't know java

Comment: okay thanks Adam

Comment: hi Adam i am trying to build a social app i have some experience in Java and little of flutter i want to start over what do you think i should head for?

Comment: @LastCode Hello! Based on your experience in Java and some experience in Flutter, you have a good foundation for building a social app. Both Java and Flutter have their own advantages and disadvantages when it comes to mobile app development.

Comment: hi i had to uninstall my android

Comment: hi Adam do you know any social app project i can check from GitHub, I am currently working on one but it will take me like forever to complete?

Comment: I am sorry that you had to go through the uninstallation and reinstallation process. I have searched a little and I have found this, but it is only dart
https://github.com/CharlyKeleb/SocialMedia-App